# how to add turn to turn navigation on map activity for multiple points

Tags: android, google-maps

i have android map with multiple points plotted from mysql data..i have added basic features of map like mylocation,zoom etc...Also added direction between multiple points from mylocation.

**Now I need to add step by step direction route or navigate between points.
Most importantly i dont want to redirect to google maps and naviagate..
all actions should happen withen my google map api.**

here is my **Mapactivity** code onMapReady

```
 @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), Util.reslatitude + "   " + Util.reslogitide+"  "+Util.resname, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        LatLng locations = new LatLng(Util.latitude,Util.longitude);
       /* Location startPoint=new Location("locationA");
        startPoint.setLatitude(Util.latitude);
        startPoint.setLongitude(Util.longitude);

        Location endPoint=new Location("locationA");
        endPoint.setLatitude(13.073226);
        endPoint.setLongitude(80.260921);

        double distance=startPoint.distanceTo(endPoint);
        Toast.makeText(this,String.valueOf(distance+" Meters"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
     /*   LatLng loc = new LatLng(13.073226, 80.260921);*/
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        //mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        mMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(locations, 4.2f));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .title("User")
                .position(locations)
        );
      /*  // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
        String url = getDirectionsUrl(locations, loc);

        DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

        // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
        downloadTask.execute(url);*/
        /*LatLng dest = new LatLng(13.036791,80.26763);
        mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().add(locations,dest).color(Color.RED) //draws straight line between points
        );*/

    }

    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

            String data = "";

            try {
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();


            parserTask.execute(result);

        }
    }


    /**
     * A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format
     */
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> {

        // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            JSONObject jObject;
            List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

                routes = parser.parse(jObject);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return routes;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
            ArrayList points = null;
            PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

            for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
                points = new ArrayList();
                lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

                for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);

                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                    points.add(position);
                }

                lineOptions.addAll(points);
                lineOptions.width(12);
                lineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);
                lineOptions.geodesic(true);

            }

// Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
            mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
        }
    }


    private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin, LatLng dest) {

        // Origin of route
        String str_origin = "origin=" + origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude;

        // Destination of route
        String str_dest = "destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;

        // Sensor enabled
        String sensor = "sensor=false";
        String mode = "mode=driving";
        // Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = str_origin + "&" + str_dest + "&" + sensor + "&" + mode;

        // Output format
        String output = "json";

        // Building the url to the web service
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" + output + "?" + parameters;


        return url;
    }


    /**
     * A method to download json data from url
     */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            urlConnection.connect();

            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
        } finally {
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
    }
```

> help me to rectify the problem

Comment: You should use google directions api for this functionality.
also you can use any third party library related to google directions.

Comment: can u please help me with the example code @AndroidGeek